# Which key cylinder do i have to buy

Tags: lock

I have a really old door in my appartement in switzerland that has a hole in it for a key cylinder. I have never seen this type before because of the 2 holes next to it. I think it could be some kind of a EURO cylinder.
Could you help me which key cylinder i have to buy?
[image: Front of the hole]
[image: other angle]

Comment: Have you taken that picture to a local retailer? Preferably an old hardware store (if you can find one) not a big-box home improvement store. You're more likely to find actual knowledge at the small hardware store (though you do get very knowledgeable people at the big-box stores _sometimes_).

Comment: not yet, i will definitely do that if i can't find the answer here, but i would prefer to order it online due to COVID